# Unable to reuse Rate Limit in response Header in Azure APIM Outbound Policy

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, rate-limiting, azure-policy

I am trying to show remaining rate calls by key in HTTP response headers using Outbound policy. I am getting `500 Internal Server Error` with below policy code.

```
<!--
    IMPORTANT:
    - Policy elements can appear only within the <inbound>, <outbound>, <backend> section elements.
    - To apply a policy to the incoming request (before it is forwarded to the backend service), place a corresponding policy element within the <inbound> section element.
    - To apply a policy to the outgoing response (before it is sent back to the caller), place a corresponding policy element within the <outbound> section element.
    - To add a policy, place the cursor at the desired insertion point and select a policy from the sidebar.
    - To remove a policy, delete the corresponding policy statement from the policy document.
    - Position the <base> element within a section element to inherit all policies from the corresponding section element in the enclosing scope.
    - Remove the <base> element to prevent inheriting policies from the corresponding section element in the enclosing scope.
    - Policies are applied in the order of their appearance, from the top down.
    - Comments within policy elements are not supported and may disappear. Place your comments between policy elements or at a higher level scope.
-->
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="X-Rate-Limit-Remaining" value="" />
        <rate-limit-by-key calls="5" renewal-period="10" counter-key="@(context.Subscription?.Key)" increment-condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200)" remaining-calls-variable-name="X-Rate-Limit-Remaining" />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
        <set-header name="X-Rate-Limit-Remaining" exists-action="append">
            <value>@((string)context.Variables["X-Rate-Limit-Remaining"])</value>
        </set-header>
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

**Error:**

I am getting below message , when i tried to remove string, its not working for me.

```
set-header (0.461 ms)
{
    "messages": [
        {
            "message": "Expression evaluation failed.",
            "expression": "(string)context.Variables[\"X-Rate-Limit-Remaining\"]",
            "details": "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."
        },
        "Expression evaluation failed. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.",
        "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'."
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is the error message? have you tried to capture OCP trace?

Comment: Try to use .As<string> or .toString()